# How do I resize the td of a table styled with bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I read http://getbootstrap.com/css/#tables which didn't mention resizing tds in any specific way, so I tried the following css:

```
.cbCell {
    width: 25px;
}

.smallerCell {
    width: 240px;
}

.textfield {
    width: 230px;
}
```

with this html

```
<thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="cbCell"><input type='checkbox' class='form-control' id='selectall'></th>
        <th class="text-center smallerCell">Employee Name</th>
        <th class="text-center smallerCell">Mail</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr id='addr0'>
        <td class="cbCell"><input type='checkbox' class='form-control case'></td>
        <td class="smallerCell"><input type="text" name='name0'  placeholder='Name' class="form-control textfield"/></td> 
        <td class="smallerCell"><input type="text" name='mail0' placeholder='Mail' class="form-control textfield"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr id='addr1'>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

The textfields have been resized but the td has not, the 'smallerCell' style isn't applied

[image: name and mail cols need to just cover the textfields]

I tried [Change column width bootstrap tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828224/change-column-width-bootstrap-tables) which didn't work for me.  I used the grid system to float the establishment info to the right, I ultimately want the name and mail columns to fit the smaller textfield size, and for there to be a margin and vertical rule dividing the People and Establishment columns.

Comment: *Don't* use this as a solution, but does `.smallerCell { width: 240px !important; }` make a change?

Comment: Also as a *test* `table { width: 510px !important }`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change table width to auto. In boot strap table width is set to 100%

```
.table {
width: 100%;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

so make it

```
.table {
width: auto;
}
```

in you css.